# Why doesn't this return the price?

Tags: javascript

just wondering how to return the price? This simply returns the whole function?

```
var amount = 0;
var price = 99.99;
var tax = 10;
var balance = 550;

function calculateTax() {
    var prices = price + tax;
    return prices;
};

calculateTax();

console.log(calculateTax);
```

Thanks

Comment: `var tax = calculateTax(); console.log(tax);`

Comment: or `console.log(calculateTax());`

Comment: To execute the function, you need to use braces at the end. `calculateTax` references the function itself.

Comment: you are not calling the function (with `()`) you are trying to log the function itself, not the result of it

Comment: The answers below will fix your code but they won't teach you anything. I would suggest that you learn how variable assignment and function calls work. This is a very basic mistake - instead of asking on Stack Overflow you'd be better served by hitting the tutorials.

Comment: Basicly you've write the function name, so it return the function content. Remember to use `()` to execute the function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you didn't hold your returned value

try like this

```
var calculate=calculateTax();

console.log(calculate);
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/vaa0dqxr/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You are not storing the returned/computed value anywhere. 
Try doing this,

```
console.log(calculateTax());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
console.log(calculateTax());
```

Because only "calculateTax" returns a function, not it`s execute result.

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to rewrite your function as below:

```
var amount = 0;
var price = 99.99;
var tax = 10;
var balance = 550;

function calculateTax(price,tax) {
    var prices = price + tax;
    return prices;
};

var calculatedTax = calculateTax(price,tax);

console.log(calculatedTax );
```

Comment: at least whoever voted negatively could have left a comment to indicate what is wrong with the answer !

Answer (score 0):

```js
var amount = 0;
var price = 99.99;
var tax = 10;
var balance = 550;

function calculateTax() {
    var prices = price + tax;
    return prices;
};

console.log(calculateTax());
```

Comment: Why call `caculateTax` twice?

Comment: ya sure not need to call again, i changed ok

Answer (score 0):

When you say console.log(calculateTax) you just output the body of the function.
To output the actual result type :

```
console.log(calculateTax())
```